# groupby.filter works on series instead of dataframes? (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

In IPython I do `groupby` on regular data frame:

```
grouped
Out[356]: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f0e78578750>
```

But `filter` on it seems to be getting Series instead of data frames:

```
     ...: def print_obj(x):
     ...:     print type(x)
     ...:     return True
     ...:



e=grouped.filter(print_obj)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-349-a93d384d3560> in <module>()
----> 1 e=grouped.filter(print_obj)

/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in filter(self, func, dropna, *args, **kwargs)
   2092                 res = path(group)
   2093
-> 2094             if res:
   2095                 indexers.append(self.obj.index.get_indexer(group.index))
   2096

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

However, when I do `apply`, I'm getting dataframes only:

```
grouped.apply(print_obj)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
...
```

`filter` docstring says I should be getting Dataframes. Why? And how can I fix that? (I want to simply drop some groups from grouped-by df).

P.S. pandas==0.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, `apply` and `filter` try different ways of looping through the data: a "slow path" that is sure to work for any function, and a "fast path" that only works for some functions. These paths can operate on whole chucks of the data (as a DataFrame) or one row at a time (as Series).

The details are subtle -- look through `pandas/core/groupby.py` if you want -- but the gist is that `print_obj` is revealing some of these internals that are not germain to what you actually want to do.

Which groups do you want to drop, and what criterion are you trying to use?